# TypeError: stripHtml is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm working a blog website using Next Js, when I try to make blog `api` for rich text-editor using `string-strip-html` then show me a error like this:

> C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN
> stack\seoBlog\backend\controllers\blogControllers.js:28
> blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
> ^
>
> TypeError: stripHtml is not a function
>
> ```
> at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\seoBlog\backend\controllers\blogControllers.js:28:18        
> at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\seoBlog\backend\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:107:9)
> at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\seoBlog\backend\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:557:8)
> at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\seoBlog\backend\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:238:12
> at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN stack\seoBlog\backend\node_modules\formidable\lib\file.js:79:5    
> at WriteStream.onfinish (_stream_writable.js:689:5)
> at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at finish (_stream_writable.js:657:10)
> at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:644:9)
> at _stream_writable.js:617:7
> at WriteStream._final (internal/fs/streams.js:355:3)
> at callFinal (_stream_writable.js:610:10)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) [nodemon] app crashed -
> ```
>
> waiting for file changes before starting...

When I saved my code then didn't show any error in my console, but when I try to show output using postman, then show me error like this. Postman show `Could not get response`

I have tried code like this:

```
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Tag = require("../models/tags");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const stripHtml = require("string-strip-html");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not upload",
      });
    }

    const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;

    let blog = new Blog();
    blog.title = title;
    blog.body = body;
    blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
    blog.mtitle = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
    blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
    blog.postedBy = req.user._id;

    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Image should be less then 1mb in size",
        });
      }
      blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }

    blog.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      }
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
};
```

I have used router perfectly and use form-data in postman also perfectly.

Don't know where is problem.

Any Suggestion please.

Comment: `const { stripHtml } = require("string-strip-html");` it's an object that contains the function as property. PS: It's the first time i've heard of the library, and this took like three minutes to find out... See e.g. the [docs](https://codsen.com/os/string-strip-html/)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to run this command and then everything will work, the reason is that this package will only work if you have Typescript

`npm i string-strip-html@4.4.1`

Answer (score 2):

I changed

```
const stripHtml = require("string-strip-html");
```

to

```
const { stripHtml } = require("string-strip-html");
```

and this worked fine for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm :p